# Comment too fast pops up even though the comment wasn't accepted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, 408-timeout

I made a short comment `direct link?    ?` and it turned out that it wasn't long enough (although the character counter was happy with it), then added a few more characters to make it happy and then I got a message saying `only 1 comment allowed every 15 seconds`.
This, although the comment 5 seconds ago wasn't actually accepted.

This is an annoying bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, it's by design.

Annoying as it is, it's intended

Answer (score -2):

If you game the comment length indicator, it will game you.

Comment: This feels like a Friday afternoon kind of response!  Love it!